# How to factorize polynomials

Tags: polynomials

How can I factorize the polynomial $$-a(b-c)(x-b)(x-c)-b(c-a)(x-a)(x-c)-c(a-b)(x-a)(x-b)?$$ Please show me the whole process step by step in an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

It is a quadratic polynomial, whose coefficient of $x^2$ is given by:

$$ -\sum_{cyc}a(b-c) = \sum_{cyc}ac-\sum_{cyc}ab = 0. $$
Its value at $x=0$ is also zero since $\sum_{cyc}(b-c)=0$, too.

It follows that your polynomial is some multiple of $x$.

Which multiple? That is easy to understand, by evaluating at $x=a$, for instance.

Comment: $(a - b) (b - c)  (c-a) x$